# Validação Client-Side (Jquery) de atributo condicional

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc

Tarde!

Estou realizando uma validação complexa numa classe específica com o seguinte código (reduzido para simplificar):

```
public class Classe1 : IValidatableObject 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id_Classe1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Id_Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual Classe2 CLASSE2 { get; set; }

    public Classe1() {
    CLASSE2 = new Classe2();
}

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
    if (this.Id_Estado == 1) 
    {
        if (CLASSE2.Nm_Classe2 == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Campo Nome é obrigatório.", new string[] { "CLASSE2.Nm_Classe2" });
    }
}
```

No controller (ModelState.IsValid) a validação está ok. Agora preciso refletir essa validação no Client-Side, com o jquery unobtrusive. Alguém pode me dar uma orientação sobre como fazer?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no plugin [Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) ?

Comment: Sim. Utilizo ele. Ocorre que estou querendo o seguinte: Caso `Id_Estado` (atributo da `classe1`) seja 1, então força a digitação de `Nm_Classe2` (atributo da `classe2` que não é `[Required]`). Exatamente o que está fazendo no código acima. Seria como se colocasse um `[Required]` condicional no atributo `CLASSE2`, mas como esse atributo é um objeto de outra classe ele simplesmente não valida no client-side.

Answer (score 1):

A quem possa interessar, achei o que estava precisando, resolvi da seguinte forma:

Criei um validador condicional que testa um atributo especifico da classe e manuseia o atributo da outra classe, assim:

```
public class Classe1 : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id_Classe1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Id_Estado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Classe2 CLASSE2 { get; set; }

    [IgualOuDiferente("Id_Estado", "1", "Igual", ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido")]
    public string Teste
    {
        get { return this.CLASSE2.Nm_Classe2; }
        set { CLASSE2.Nm_Classe2 = value; }
    }
}
```

Ou seja, se o atributo "Id_Estado" for "Igual" a "1", exige que informe o `Nm_Classe2`, mesmo este estando em outra classe (`Classe2`) sem o `[Required]`.

Na View fica assim:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Teste)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Teste)
```

Valew!

Comment: Criativo, embora fora do padrão. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Implementando atributos customizados que implementem uma interface chamada `IClientValidatable`. [Nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003400/jquery-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-of-custom-attribute) os usuários mostram em detalhes como fazer isso.

Neste caso, o seu evento `Validate` entra como um bônus de validação, apenas do lado do servidor.

Comment: Li a pergunta, inclusive já implemento um método customizado que testa um campo específico que, caso contenha um determinado valor, requer o preenchimento de outro campo. É exatamente o que quero, acontece que me deparei com o problema de que o campo que estou requerendo fica em outra classe, e não encontro como fazer essa validação. Se eu colocar um `[Required]` logo acima do atributo `CLASSE2`, ele não funciona pois é um objeto que contem outros atributos.

Comment: Coloque o atributo de validação no campo que deve ser validado da sua `CLASSE2`. O `ModelState` é capaz de validar uma propriedade de uma classe agregada mesmo se a classe em questão for a classe que contém sua classe agregada.

Comment: Agradeço a sugestão, o problema é que tem tela que utiliza essa mesma classe e, nessa tela, ela não pode ser Required. Assim, eu queria realmente tornar um atributo de outra classe requerido de acordo com o valor definido em um atributo na classe atual (exatamente como descrito acima).